# How to get text from a DLL back into an EXE

Tags: c#, windows, dll, exe

I appreciate any help someone suggests and want to thank you ahead of time.

So my issue it that I have a DLL that is created in C#.  The DLL performs a bunch of actions on a users machine.  I would like to add a logging type feature in the DLL after each step is performed, then display the step in an output window on the C# EXE (sort of what Visual Studio looks like when you compile code)

The DLL is referenced in my UI EXE application.

So to some things up:
-My C# EXE is the User Interface which (for now has a rich text box window I'd like output from the DLL to go to) 
-My DLL is called from the EXE using System Reflections which is pointed to the exacted method in the DLL I want to run, as each step in the method is performed I want to some how send a string or let the EXE output window know there is some new data and display it.

What is the best way to go about doing this?  I've thought of a few but the seem like they would not be very good.  If I put output to a random text file and have the EXE look at the same file there could be locking issues.  That is an example of the ideas I had but I know there is a better way to do this.

I don't know everything and I'm hoping to learn something from this question.  I did some research on my own and the answer was not clear.  I'm not a C# expert but I hope to be someday :)

Comment: Too broad, a suggestion is to add a log library to your dll like [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/), study the options available and read the produced file back in your exe.

Comment: Wow, that seems really good.  I'm not familiar with this at all but I'll read into it.  Just a quick glance over it seems like it will help.  I take it I would setup some listener class in the EXE waiting for an event of some sort?  I'll dig into this but thanks for taking the time to read and suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Here is something I have used to do what you are looking for.
http://wintrace.codeplex.com/releases/view/57038

Reference the "GridViewTraceListner" dll
Create a Window form, add datagrid "dgvTraceView", add label "lblCounter", add button "button1".

Next add the following on the form load.

```
TraceListener trlistener = new GridViewTraceListener.GridViewTraceListener
                                 (dgvTraceView, lblCounter);
Trace.Listeners.Add(trlistener);
```

On the button click event add something like this.

```
Logger.Log("MyTest"); // this is a method in the external dll.
```

Now in your "external" dll and something like this.

```
public static void Log(string text)
{
    ConsoleTraceListener listener = new ConsoleTraceListener();
    Trace.Listeners.Add(listener);
    Trace.WriteLine(text);
    Trace.Listeners.Remove(listener);
    Trace.Close();
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks, I will look at this too.  Sorry for slow response I keep getting dragged into different things at work.... If only I could sit here an have no one pester me lol, does not seem like that will ever happen though :)  I'll post which option I end up using

Answer (score 0):

You should consider the [observer design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). You can create event handlers for notifying your UI project that an event has occurred. Then you can assign functions to your event handlers from your UI project and output logging directly to your RichTextBox.

You will need to create a custom EventArgs class if you want to add parameters to default EventArgs. Then you can setup a delegate for handling your event.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1474/Events-and-event-handling-in-C

Comment: I'm not sure what this has to do with the question asked (which is not about being able to run functions in the DLL). The question asks about communicating status back to the executable while the DLL executes functionality.

Comment: Ken is correct, I do have it already referenced with the EXE btw.

Comment: My apologies. I somehow skipped over the fact that you were already referencing the DLL. I've modified my answer more appropriately.

Comment: No problem Cameron, sorry I would have elaborated more but I co-worker started pestering me lol.  As for those design patterns you speak of I have only just began to learn of there existance.  I've started Master's program and they briefly stated something but I will admit that I'm very ignorant there too so I'm going to look into what you suggested now maybe I can kill 2 birds with one stone work and school :) thanks again